# Fill PHP table randomly with array

Tags: php, arrays, html-table, fill

I'm stuck with some problem - can't fill my table with random values from array. Can someone help?

```html
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>

<form action="table2.php" method="POST">
<p>N: <input name = "row"; maxlength="2" size="1" value="5"></p>
<p>M: <input name = "col"; maxlength="2" size="1" value="7"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="zero" value="go"/>
</form>
<?php

$array1 = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8");
$rand_keys = array_rand($array1, 2);
echo $array1[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
function draw_table($row,$col) {
    $table = "<table>";
    $i = 1;
    do {
        $table .= "<tr>";
        $j = 1;
        do {
            $table .= "<td>X  $i Y  $j";
            $table .= "</td>";
            $j++;
        }
        while($j <= $col);
        $table .= "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    while($i <= $row);
    $table .= "</table>";
    return $table;
}

if(isset($_POST['zero'])) {
    $rows = $_POST['row']; 
    $cols = $_POST['col']; 
    
    echo(draw_table($rows, $cols));
}
?>
```

I tried to use array_rand, but can't understand how modify this code for that function

```
$table .= "<td>X  $i Y  $j";
$table .= "</td>";
$j++;
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want a table filled with values from the array?

Comment: Yes. I have array, i want to fill my table with random values from it.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the `do while()` loop so I am going to hopefully simplify your life here:

```
$words = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8");

$rows = rand(1, 20);
$cols = rand(1, 20);

echo '<table>'."\n";
for($r = 1; $r <= $rows; ++$r)
{
    echo '<tr>'."\n";
    for($c = 1; $c <= $cols; ++$c)
    {
        // One word
        $td_text = $words[rand(0,(count($words)-1))];

        // One to five words separated by a space
        // $td_text = substr(str_repeat($words[rand(0,(count($words)-1))].' ', rand(1, 5)), 0, -1);

        echo '<td>'.$td_text.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>'."\n";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Thats works good, but i want to replace numbers in my array to words. Thanks for this example.
i fill my array with numbers for simpification.

Comment: @TwinSpike Are you looking to fill it with real words or just random letters? From where would you get the words?

Comment: From my array. For a start.

Comment: @TwinSpike If you haven't checked it out yet, there is yet a newer update. Thanks

Comment: From my array. For a start.
Now i going to make of the words links, thats will redirect for another php file, in which transmitted chosen word and its coordinate

Comment: @TwinSpike Nice! If my answer helped, please feel free to accept it.

Comment: Yes, thats works nice to. i will study this two examples. Thanks!